# adb.exe has stopped working with Android Studio 4.3.1 and Android 9.+

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, adb, android-virtual-device

With the latest clean installation of Android Studio with all the recommended settings I have this continuous error when I try to start an emulated device. The device starts up correctly and works properly but the "adb.exe has stopped working" popups continue to appear if they are closed, furthermore it is not possible to link the device with Android Studio because it is not recognized. Even if I download a previous image of Android (Android 9.0) I have the same problem.

The only plugins installed are Dart and Flutter.
The question could be repeated but I did not find solutions for this problem, or rather, the solutions found did not allow me to close this problem.

Before this update everything was working properly.
In this case we speak of a clean installation.

When I try to start the "main.dart" application to install it on the device the only error that appears is "Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:"

Android Studio 3.4.1 Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.0-5611747

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938#issuecomment-499741574, https://twitter.com/FlutterDev/status/1137033935089807365

Answer (score 7):

There is a **temporary fix** for now (if you're using Windows)!

***1st*** Close *Android Studio*

***2nd***  Open CMD and write:  `taskkill /f /im adb.exe`

***3rd*** Download this file: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

***4th*** Go to

> C:\Users[your-username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

and replace the "platform-tools" folder with the new one that you just downloaded.

ps: (a) don't forget to keep the backup (b) the AppData is a hidden folder

Comment: Thanks, after reverting platform-tools to earlier version I get no more adb.exe crashes.

Comment: @onosecond I have the same problem here. I closed the android studio and followed the second step but it said that `ERROR: The process "adb.exe" not found`. I thought that the process is already closed and continued the third step. I downloaded, unzipped, extracted and replaced the folder as you directed. Again when I started the android studio, the same error occurred."`adb.exe has stopped working`". Please direct me what to do next to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

below solution work for me,

1. go to control panel and remove all adb.exe
2. Remove all cache and delete device and restart.
3. adb kill-server, adb start-server also works.
4. in case still error window (adb.exe has stopped working error) -> go to Android Studio > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Untick "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging" (this checking physical device or not, remember tick again in future when required).