# 'adb.exe has stopped working' Popup Message Over and Over

Tags: android-studio, adb

Yesterday, after an Android Studio update, when I run any ADB emulator in android studio it runs fine but I get a popup message every 2 seconds saying 'adb.exe has stoppped working'. So i basically can't work on it.

This problem was experienced by another user here ([ad.exe has stopped working with Android Studio 4.3.1 and Android 9.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507194/ad-exe-has-stopped-working-with-android-studio-4-3-1-and-android-9)) and I tried to comment on their thread to add more information (things I've tried) but I did not have enough status to leave a 'comment' and when i added an 'answer' to add this information some stickler for the rules suggested a mod delete it so they did. So this appears the only way to add more information to the problem.

Here are some of the things i've tried:

- Recreating the emulated device
- restarting the adb server
- uninstalling/reinstalling Android SDK Platform-tools on Android Studio
- uninstalling/reinstalling HAXM, USB Driver
- restarting computer
- you can kill the extra spawned adb.exe processess with "taskkill /F /IM adb.exe /T" but it does not stop the processes from spawning nor does it get rid of the popup messages.
- other things I cant remember at the moment.

The problem is unlike other similar problems on stackoverflow because the emulator is fully functional.. it's just these irritating popup messages that keep coming up. They each spawn their own adb.exe process which then goes away after accepting the popup message.

The popup message is a windows crash error with this info:

"adb.exe has stopped working"
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: adb.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    30cf30aa
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_375c
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.24441
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5cb937ce
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 000ce9a3
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 375c
  Additional Information 2: 375cda87d3cdf85857bdcf6ea96d4da3
  Additional Information 3: cb04
  Additional Information 4: cb04670b7601c3b9c6d3a9f57bcccc74

I'm using:
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1