# ADB.exe has stopped working on API 29 AVD

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I have created a new AVD API29 to test my application. The AVD runs fine but I keep getting ADB.exe has stopped working over and over. So, I have tried an AVD with API28 and it worked fine.

How do I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507194/adb-exe-has-stopped-working-with-android-studio-4-3-1-and-android-9

Comment: Thanks @bl4ckr0se. Though, that does not help. Downgrading adb.exe causes the emulator to display that you have an obsolete version of adb and adb does not work. You cannot debug the application or even drag and drop the apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb.exe has stopped working with Android Studio 4.3.1 and Android 9.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507194/adb-exe-has-stopped-working-with-android-studio-4-3-1-and-android-9)

Comment: For the use that I did I had not yet gone into debug and the adb.exe problem I had solved with a downgrade. However I have seen the update 29.0.1 now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those experiencing the problem, Google has released 29.0.1. Update to the latest version and the problem is resolved. ADB is working again and for API29.